# Entity Framework create relationships and contraints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have access of a database which has two tables. These two tables have a common key which from the documentation means are the table are related. When I inquired about the two tables I was told that of course there is relationship but is not enforced.

I used Visual Studio 2010 and created an Entity Model and as expected its shows two tables with no relationship.

I need to create a relationship between these two on the model and have two questions.
First I am using asp.net MVC 3 and want a relationship which is 0..1 to many. This is because when I delete a value or update in Table A, I want related values to be affected.

Second I need help on showing these related values from my entity model on same page on my view.

Comment: A common FK is not a relation ship between the tables. If you need to make a relationship, first find your requirements and then you can decide which table has to refer to the other.

Comment: @peer From the documentation they sent, the two tables are related but they don't want a relationship enforced on their database because of other applications that access the database as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I am providing some links of you-tube video this will help full to understand clearly.
[Microsoft Entity Framework 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQqzTr-1waE) and second one is [Microsoft Entity Framework 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTasIwcXNyE), this will be surely help you to understand.